# Update document in MongoDb when _id is an object

Tags: mongodb

I'm having an issue when I try to update the following document in my MongoDb collection:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "EDIEL" : "1111",
        "StartDate" : {
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "Ticks" : NumberLong(636082776000000000)
        }
    },
    "Versions" : [ 
        {
            "Id" : 121031547,
            "VersionNumber" : 0,
            "Quantity" : 5.58,
            "Quality" : "E01",
            "Created" : {
                "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-09-08T23:49:23.000Z"),
                "Ticks" : NumberLong(636089753630000000)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 137414738,
            "VersionNumber" : 0,
            "Quantity" : 19.67,
            "Quality" : "E01",
            "Created" : {
                "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-09-08T23:49:23.000Z"),
                "Ticks" : NumberLong(636089753630000000)
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 121031550,
            "VersionNumber" : 1,
            "Quantity" : 19.67,
            "Quality" : "E01",
            "Created" : {
                "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T05:37:38.000Z"),
                "Ticks" : NumberLong(636147850580000000)
            }
        }
    ],
    "MeterId" : 1165,
    "OriginalId" : 121031547,
    "Unit" : "KWH",
    "ReadingFrequency" : "PT15M",
    "EndDate" : {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-31T22:15:00.000Z"),
        "Ticks" : NumberLong(636082785000000000)
    }
}
```

I need to update the `Quantity` to 25.0 of version with `Id` 137414738 in the `Versions` array.

My update query looks like this:

```
collection.update(
    // query 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "EDIEL" : "1111",
            "StartDate" : {
                "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"),
                "Ticks" : NumberLong(636082776000000000)
            }
        }
    },

    // update 
    {
        $set: { "Versions.1.Quantity": 25.0 }
    },

    // options 
    {
        "multi" : false,  // update only one document 
        "upsert" : false  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query 
    }
);
```

However, the shell outputs that 0 records has been updated.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? :-)

**EDIT**

The write result looks like this:

```
"ok" : undefined,
"nInserted" : 0.0,
"nUpserted" : 0.0,
"nMatched" : 0.0,
"nModified" : 0.0,
"nRemoved" : 0.0,
```

Comment: Is `nMatched` also 0. If yes, modify your `query` for each of the 3 final keys in `_id`

Comment: your query is working fine

Comment: Hmm, `nMatched` is 0, yes, but I am pretty sure it's right key I'm passing in? No? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in Robomongo. Worked fine in a normal cmd shell